# Generate Alter statements of partition of all existing tables from Oracle views in 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle19c

I want to generate dynamically the below alter code(the below one is an eg, it will differ table to table) for all the partitioned tables in 12c DB.

Some tables may be partitioned on RANGE, LIST etc.

The column name, partition type will also change as per the table.

```
ALTER TABLE EMP
MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE (START_DATE) 
( PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (date'2021-1-1') ) ONLINE;
```

I have already created tables without partition in another db and now want to partition those tables which were partitioned in the source db. So want a simple script which can create code to partition the tables in the target db. Note - all tables have different partition and my goal is to make them sync with source. Only data differs in both the DBs.

Comment: Setting `INTERVAL (1)` on a DATE RANGE partition does not make much sense. What do you like to achieve? Maybe this one gives an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948055/partition-table-rename-automatically-in-oracle/60948935#60948935

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit explained my requirement in the description, please check. I will check the link

Comment: RANGE partitions are created automatically, why do want to create a script for it? Why do you like the have equal partitions in two databases? It might not even possible if the data is different.

Comment: I created the tables in another db without partition thru db link. We cant do refresh in the another db. Now after data loading, I am thinking to create a generic script which can create code for partition from source db, which can be run in the target.

Comment: Prior Oracle 18 you cannot convert a non-partitioned table to a partitioned table with a simple `ALTER TABLE ...` statement. You have to use the `RDBMS_REDEFINITION` package see [Changing a Nonpartitioned Table into a Partitioned Table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html)

Comment: You should see all information in views ALL_IND_PARTITIONS, 
ALL_PART_INDEXES, 
ALL_PART_TABLES, 
ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS, 
ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS A function which covers all type of partitions would be rather long. Have a look at my linked answer above, it shows you a starting point. Another example is https://stackoverflow.com/a/59468025/3027266 and