# How to automate partition drop and alter table activity in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, partition, database-partitioning

I need a procedure that will help me to drop partition older than 3 months (current month + last 3 older months). And then I need to create the new partition in sequence.

for example if current partition is May22, then I need to drop Jan22 and create Jan23 partition. Can someone help me with the procedure?

Comment: Could the partitions be named in the format of CCYYMM?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465024/create-table-with-partition-year-and-subpartition-month-in-oracle-12c/59468025#59468025

Answer (score 1):

Use [interval partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/partition-concepts.html#GUID-C121EA1B-2725-4464-B2C9-EEDE0C3C95AB) - available starting from Oracle 11.

You will need *no procedure* for a *creation of a partition*, because the partition will be created automatically with the first insert of the data with the corresponding date.

You will still need a basic code for *drop partition* - rolling window is not supported in the interval partitioning.

Using the  [partition extended names](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Syntax-for-Schema-Objects-and-Parts-in-SQL-Statements.html#GUID-FED2E424-3F06-4B2B-88D2-DE043CA6E0E4) makes it much easier that if you use partition names

*Example*

**Create Interval Partitioned Table**

```
CREATE TABLE  test_part
   (trans_date DATE, 
    pad  VARCHAR2(100)
   )
PARTITION BY RANGE (trans_date)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
(
   PARTITION part_init values LESS THAN (DATE'2020-01-01')
);
```

Note - use a *less than date* long in the history for the initial partition so that no data will be inserted there.
This partition will remain empty and *will not be dropped*, otherwise you encounter
`ORA-14083: cannot drop the only partition of a partitioned table`.

**Create Partition**

Now populate that table with few rows.
Note that there is no need for *explicite* create partition as we use *interval partitioning* and the partitions are created automatically.

```
insert into test_part(trans_date, pad)
select add_months(trunc(sysdate),-3)-rownum trans_date, 'X' pad 
from dual connect by level <= 3;
```

**Drop Partition**

The implenetation of the rolling window consists of two steps
First check the transactions dates that are older than three months

```
select distinct trunc(trans_date) drop_date from test_part
where trans_date < add_months(trunc(sysdate),-3)
order by 1 desc;

DROP_DATE          
-------------------
08.01.2022 00:00:00
07.01.2022 00:00:00
06.01.2022 00:00:00
```

Now you need to drop partitions for the above selected days.
You can use the *partition extended names to do so, without a need to know the partition name and the *ugly* LONG `HIGH_VALUE`.

Example for the day `DATE'2022-07-07'`

```
alter table TEST_PART drop partition for (DATE'2022-07-07');
```

You may pack the clean up logic in a simple procedure

```
create or replace procedure rolling_window as
  v_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
 for cur in (
    select distinct trunc(trans_date) drop_date from test_part
    where trans_date < add_months(trunc(sysdate),-3)
    order by 1 desc)
  loop
     v_sql := q'[alter table TEST_PART drop partition for (DATE']'||
         to_char(cur.drop_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')||q'[') ]';
     dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
     execute immediate v_sql;   
  end loop;
end;
/
```

If you use *global indexes* you may want to add the clause `UPDATE INDEXES` in the `ALTER TABLE`to keep the index *usable* after the operation.

Comment: I tried plugging in DATE values instead of PARTITION name and got an error that I couldn't resolve. I do agree, dates are better. My attempt  failed on the to_char call and I don't understand why. Any help would be appreciated  /*
ddl( 'ALTER TABLE ' || aPart.TABLE_NAME || ' DROP PARTITION FOR(DATE ' || TO_CHAR(aPart.high_value,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ')');
*/

Comment: The trick is as easy as you must forgot the view `USER_TAB_PARTITIONS`, simple calculate each day the partition that should be truncated with e.g. `add_months(trunc(sysdate),-2)` - to keep 2 months of data. @Pugzly

Comment: Sorry I seem to be missing your point as that is on of the views I'm joining to get the high_value for each PARTITION. I laid out a complete test CASE and the to_char call is producing an error when I put that in place of using the PARTITION name to drop the PARTITION. I appreciate your help and expertise as I dont know how to proceed

Comment: @Pugzly *you* ask *extra* question, but I added some explanation in my answer for you;)

Comment: thanks for responding and the extra effort its greatly appreciated. While your solution works I'm baffled as to why I can't port my solution to extended dates. I thought it would be easy but I missing something. As for the.update global indexes l stayed away from that and used a generic rebuild index procedure that can be called anytime via a scheduler or placed in my block like I showed below. This way I kill 2 birds with one stone:-) If I can't figure out my issue without overhauling my implentation ill post a new question. Once again thanks but I'm curious how to fix my issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process we use to RENAME and drop PARTITIONs that are range INTERVAL. Just add the procedures to your scheduler.

They work great

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ddl(p_cmd varchar2) 
 authid current_user
is
t1 pls_integer;
BEGIN 
t1 := dbms_utility.get_time; 

dbms_output.put_line(p_cmd);

 execute immediate p_cmd;

dbms_output.put_line((dbms_utility.get_time - t1)/100 || ' seconds');

END;
/

CREATE TABLE PARTITION_RETENTION (
   seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    RETENTION INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(0),
 CONSTRAINT
partition_retention_pk primary key (table_name),
CONSTRAINT CHK_NON_ZERO_DAYS CHECK (
        RETENTION > INTERVAL '0' DAY
    ),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_WHOLE_DAYS CHECK (
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM RETENTION) = 0
        AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM RETENTION) = 0
        AND EXTRACT(SECOND FROM RETENTION) = 0
    )
);

insert into PARTITION_RETENTION (TABLE_NAME, RETENTION) 
select 'T1', interval '10' day from dual union all
select 'T3', interval '15' day from dual union all
select 'T4', 15 * interval '1' day from dual union all
select 'T5', 5 * interval '1 00:00:00' day to second from dual;

CREATE TABLE t1 (     
 seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   dt   DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'DAY'))
(
   PARTITION OLD_DATA values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
);
/

INSERT into t1 (dt)
with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '2022-01-01', numtodsinterval(1,'DAY') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv < date '2022-02-01')
select dt from dt;
/

create index t1_global_ix on t1 (dt);
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MaintainPartitions IS  EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE, -6550);

    CURSOR PartTables IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, INTERVAL
    FROM USER_PART_TABLES 
    WHERE PARTITIONING_TYPE = 'RANGE' 
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;

    CURSOR TabParts(aTableName VARCHAR2) IS 
    SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
    FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
 WHERE regexp_like(partition_name,'^SYS_P[[:digit:]]{1,10}')  AND
 TABLE_NAME = aTableName AND
table_name not like 'BIN$%'
      and    interval is not null
    ORDER BY PARTITION_POSITION;

    ym INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH;
    ds INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
    newPartName VARCHAR2(30);
    PERIOD TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN

    FOR aTab IN PartTables LOOP 
        BEGIN       
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aTab.INTERVAL||'; END;' USING OUT ds;
            ym := NULL; 
        EXCEPTION 
            WHEN EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE THEN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aTab.INTERVAL||'; END;' USING OUT ym;
                ds := NULL;         
        END;            

        FOR aPart IN TabParts(aTab.TABLE_NAME) LOOP         
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT PERIOD;
            IF ds IS NOT NULL THEN
                IF ds >= INTERVAL '7' DAY THEN
                    -- Weekly partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"IYYY"W"IW';
                ELSE
                    -- Daily partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYYMMDD';
                END IF;
            ELSE
                IF ym = INTERVAL '3' MONTH THEN
                    -- Quarterly partition 
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYY"Q"Q';
                ELSE
                    -- Monthly partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYYMM';
                END IF;
            END IF;

            IF newPartName <> aPart.PARTITION_NAME THEN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aTab.TABLE_NAME||' RENAME PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||' TO '||newPartName;
            END IF;             
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

END MaintainPartitions;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rebuild_index
authid current_user
is

BEGIN 
        for i in (
            select index_owner, index_name, partition_name, 'partition' ddl_type
           from all_ind_partitions
           where status = 'UNUSABLE'
           union all
           select owner, index_name, null, null
           from all_indexes
           where status = 'UNUSABLE'
       )
       loop
         if i.ddl_type is null then
          ddl('alter index '||i.index_owner||'.'||i.index_name||' rebuild parallel 4 online');
         else
          ddl('alter index '||i.index_owner||'.'||i.index_name||' modify '||i.ddl_type||' '||i.partition_name||' rebuild parallel 4 online');
         end if;
       end loop;
 END;
/


EXEC MaintainPartitions;


DECLARE
    CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION, -14758);

    CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION, -14083);

   ts TIMESTAMP;
 
   CURSOR TablePartitions IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, p.HIGH_VALUE, t.INTERVAL, RETENTION, DATA_TYPE
    FROM USER_PART_TABLES t
        JOIN USER_TAB_PARTITIONS p USING (TABLE_NAME)
        JOIN USER_PART_KEY_COLUMNS pk ON pk.NAME = TABLE_NAME
        JOIN USER_TAB_COLS tc USING (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME)
        JOIN PARTITION_RETENTION r USING (TABLE_NAME)
    WHERE        pk.object_type     = 'TABLE' AND
   t.partitioning_type = 'RANGE' AND 
    REGEXP_LIKE (tc.data_type, '^DATE$|^TIMESTAMP.*'); 

BEGIN

    FOR aPart IN TablePartitions LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT ts;
        IF ts < SYSTIMESTAMP - aPart.RETENTION THEN
            BEGIN
             ddl('alter table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' drop partition '||aPart.partition_name);
 
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION THEN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cant drop the only partition '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
  
   ddl('ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' TRUNCATE PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME);
                                                   WHEN CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION THEN
                    BEGIN
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Drop last partition '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL ()';
 
 ddl('alter table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' drop partition '||aPart.partition_name);

                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL( '||aPart.INTERVAL||' )';            
                    EXCEPTION
                        WHEN CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION THEN 
                            -- Depending on the order the "last" partition can be also the "only" partition at the same time
                                                 
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL( '||aPart.INTERVAL||' )';    

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cant drop the only partition '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
  
         ddl('ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' TRUNCATE PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME);                
               END;
            END;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
   rebuild_index();
END;
```